# Handle unrelated serial api calls in RxSwift

Tags: api, semaphore, swift5, rx-swift

I have a requirement to get responses from **multiple requests** with different models in RxSwift. I want to do this without GCD or Semaphore and only with **RxSwift**.
I try this code but have some problems with in different responses with different models and counts of results objects.

```
 Observable.zip(service.fetchAlbums(), service.fetchUsers())
.subscribe(onNext: { (albums, users) in
        print(albums)
        print(users)
    })
    .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

Comment: What are the problems you are having?

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine.

```
import RxSwift

func example(service: Service, disposeBag: DisposeBag) {
    Observable.zip(service.fetchAlbums(), service.fetchUsers())
        .subscribe(onNext: { (albums, users) in
            print(albums)
            print(users)
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}

protocol Service {
    func fetchAlbums() -> Observable<[Album]>
    func fetchUsers() -> Observable<[User]>
}

struct Album { }
struct User { }
```